# Android Shows Super Long Scrolling Web Page -- This is NOT Correct Behavior

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

Maybe there's some magic I don't know about with scrolling on Android?

I've got a website that works fine in IE7, IE8, IE9, FireFox, Chrome, AND Safari on desktop.  It also works fine in Safari on iPhone.

However, one of my Android 2.3.7 friends informs me that he has Opera and the default browser on his Android.  In both of those browsers, the scrollable view doesn't end at the bottom of the page.  When you get to the very end where the dark grey footer ends, you can go right past it and see solid cream-colored background going on for miles of scrolling!!

I have NO IDEA what could cause this!

Can anyone throw me a bone here?

Here's the site for anyone who might have Android 2.3.7 or another version of Android to test.  Like I said, happens in both default AND opera browsers.

http://wwwa1nbkclientsitecom.zippysites.com/

UPDATE:  I removed the **overflow-y** property from the HTML style tag in the stylesheet.  I had another Android 2.* user test it.  Its still broken.  And now my next guess is that this might be broken due to the fancy floating menu at the top.  Early versions of Android only had partial support for **position: fixed**

I'll try disabling the position: fixed menu and get it tested again.

UPDATE 2: I got it tested.  Its still broken.  I'm presently installing Google's Android SDK for the Emulator functionality.  It'll let me specify old versions of Android to test.  If I narrow down the problem, I'll post the answer here.  Until then, if anyone has an idea of what's going on, please post your idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the dynamic google map in the footer.  It had nothing to do with my page layout or style.  Everything I did was fine.  Removing the dynamic google map fixed it.  SOLUTION: Replace with a STATIC google map.  Its kind of bad to be using dynamic map embedded in page for a mobile device anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me in the latest version of Chrome on an Android 4.0.4 tablet.

However, I think the problem may lie with the other browsers' interpretation of `overflow-y: scroll;` on your `<html>` tag.

Try removing that property. You shouldn't need it on the `<html>` tag anyway.

Comment: overflow-y: scroll???  What in the world.  That doesn't show up on the desktop. That must be something being added by Wordpress.  The theme has some php code in the html tag that says language_attributes() and that's the only thing I could attribute it to.  I better investigate this.

Comment: OHH you're talking about in the stylesheet.  Weird.  That's a Twenty Twelve default theme configuration.  And they were saying how Twenty Twelve is supposed to be super great for mobile.  Its mobile-first even...  O_o

Comment: I removed it from the stylesheet.  I'll see if I can get the Android 2.3.7 user who reported the bug to test it again now.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok I went and looked into this and Chris Coyier has some info that explains WHY they probably put it in twenty Twelve:

Comment: Woops.  Hit enter.  He says "This is invalid CSS, but it works in everything except Opera. The reason for this is to prevent *centering jumps* when navigating back and forth between pages with enough content to have a vertical scroll bar and pages that do not."   Whatever all that means...

Comment: Strange. I have never had any problems such as those he described. I would say that it is simply causing more problems than it is solving at this point.